# OutofMemoryError listview sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

Im working with sqlite in android and now i need to populate a database with more than 50 images and description, in the database im saving the image name and then i save the image on the resources.
The problem is on a listview, in which i use the images using the following code.

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(poiAtual.get_imagemURI(),"drawable",getPackageName());
            holder.foto.setImageResource(resId);
```

When i scroll up and down fast the app will crash and show the outofmemory error. Is there a more efficient way of doing this??

Thanks

Edit: Here is my getview

```
    private class POIListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<POI> {
    public POIListAdapter() {
        super (Lista.this, R.layout.item_listview, POIs);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
      // lstPOIs.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);//TODO PARA TESTAR FORMA DE A LISTA NAO TER LAG, usar viewholder
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.id= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtID);
            holder.nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNomePOI);
            holder.descricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
            holder.foto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivFoto);
            view.setTag(holder);

        }
     else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        }


        POI poiAtual = POIs.get(position);

        //TextView id=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtID);
        holder.id.setText(Integer.toString(poiAtual.get_id()));
        //TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNomePOI);
        holder.nome.setText(poiAtual.get_nomePOI());
        //TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTema);
       // phone.setText(poiAtual.get_tema());
        //TextView descricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
        holder.descricao.setText(poiAtual.get_descricao());
      // ImageView ivFoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivFoto);
       //ivContactImage.setImageURI(poiAtual.get_imagemURI());


        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(poiAtual.get_imagemURI(),"drawable",getPackageName());
        holder.foto.setImageResource(resId);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the getView() method of your adapter.

Comment: How big are the images?  You should only get/display appropriately sized images for the list.  getView() looks good though.

Comment: @BillMote They are all smaller than 1mb,i tried to compress. You mean the resolution?? They are somewhere bettween 800*480 and 1920*1080. I only have one size of each image, should i have a hdpi and mhdpi and like that?

Comment: Having appropriately sized images might help the situation as any device with a lower *dpi almost certainly has higher resource constraints.  As a quick test just through R.drawable.ic_launcher (or R.mipmap.ic_launcher) into each image and fast scroll.  If you don't get OOM issues you're going to have to reduce the size of your images.  Lazy loading them and dynamically resizing could work as solution vs. addint *dpi images.

Comment: @BillMote with the ic_launcher the performance were a lot better, and it didnt crash. Now the problem is that i need full sized images to put when you click one listview item. Will i have to have 2 images of each one?? Thanks

Comment: Yep.  You *always* want to use appropriately sized images for the use.  If you have a thumbnail sized image in a list then you should use a thumbnail sized image.  You should probably lazy load them, resizing them on the fly where required and caching them so you only take that hit once.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy load your images, resizing them appropriately for the use case and store them in a local cache so you only take the resize hit the 1st time you need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should start [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) for best practices when loading bitmaps. If you are loading very large bitmaps into an imageview you should scale the bitmap to bounds of the imageview so you are not wasting unnecessary memory. Something like this:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

or you can use a Image library such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) that takes care of most of the overhead for you such as memory caching, scaling, etc.

You should also be conscious of hard references that may keep an imageview from being destroyed creating a memory leak.

You should almost *never* ever use `android:largeHeap="true"`. Usually this is used as a crutch for bad programming. Here is a snippet from the [Android developers page](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html):

> However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a
>   small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such
>   as a large photo editing app). Never request a large heap simply
>   because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix—you should
>   use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being
>   allocated and why it must be retained. Yet, even when you're confident
>   your app can justify the large heap, you should avoid requesting it to
>   whatever extent possible. Using the extra memory will increasingly be
>   to the detriment of the overall user experience because garbage
>   collection will take longer and system performance may be slower when
>   task switching or performing other common operations.